# Java - Game crashing, OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: java, android, view, crash, android-canvas

I have a game that has 2 simple screens drawn with canvas and view. One for my game and one for a lose screen. When I lose and want to go back to the game, my game crashes and throws an Out Of Bounds Exception on the following code and crashes:

```
    pauseBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pausebackground);
    pausedText = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.play);
    cont = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cont);
    box = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.box);
```

The weird thing is, I've only actually seen that error a few times and cant seem to imitate it. When I run the app now on my emulator, it runs fine and doesnt crash. But when I put it on my phone, it crashes.

This is how I am changing views:

```
    View playView = new PlayScreen(getContext());
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();

    parent.addView(playView);
    parent.removeView(this);
    parent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
```

Why is it doing this my mind is blown

Comment: OurOfMemoryError or OutOfBoundsException? If the former (which I'm pretty sure it is), then it can be any combination of these: images are too large, you're holding references to Bitmaps without recycling them, you're not properly downsampling larger files when necessary, etc. Without seeing more code and information about your project, though, it's pretty difficult to tell you what's the biggest cause of your problem.

Comment: How do you recycle them?

Comment: Bitmap.recycle() when it's no longer needed, where Bitmap is your instance of a Bitmap object

Answer (score 0):

```
manifest file in this code use:-

 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"                   //This line add in application tag
```

Comment: can you explain why this will help? Also, this won't change anything on pre-Honeycomb devices.